# PDF RANGE VBA "How do I Reference a cell Value as the PDF Range cut off"

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, range

This is probably simple to do but not sure how to execute. I would like to reference a cell that holds
Coordinates to the last row in which the PDF Range will save up to.... How do I make this work??

```
Sub SaveDispoPDF()

Dim pdf_range As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DISPO")

EndRow = ws.Cells("R2")

Set pdf_range = ws.Range("A1:ENDROW")

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ws.Range("V2")

Filename = ws.Range("A2")

pdf_range.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FilePath & Filename & ".pdf"

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Image]

I tried calling the cell as worksheet.cells & worksheet.Range

Comment: Try `EndRow = ws.Range("R2")` `Set pdf_range = ws.Range("A1:" & ENDROW)`